# Increment/Decrement when a radioButton is clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pair of radiobuttons on each repeater element, only one can be selected at a time. Both are unchecked on page load.
There are two values on the page, for eg: Financed and Non-Financed.
When the financed radiobutton is clicked, I need to increment the value of the financed div by 1, if the nonfinanced radiobutton was selected before I need to decrement the financed div by 1 as well .

Heres the code I'm using which only adds right now:

```
var financedDiv = Number($('.financed div').html().trim());
    var NonfinancedDiv = Number($('.non-financed div').html().trim());
    var cbxFinancedInvioces = $('#cbxFinancedInvoices');
    var cbxUnfinancedInvoices = $('#cbxUnFinancedInvoices');
    cbxFinancedInvioces.on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {                
            financedDiv = financedDiv + 1;
            $('.financed div').html(financedDiv);
        }            
    });

    cbxUnfinancedInvoices.on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {               
            NonfinancedDiv = NonfinancedDiv + 1;
            $('.non-financed div').html(NonfinancedDiv);
        }
    });
```

this adds the value just fine, but Im not sure how to find if the box was clicked before and under which condition to decrease the value.

HTML as under:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 dvContainer"><div class="row dashboard-nmbers text-center">
<div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="financed">
        <div>0</div>
        <p>Financed</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="non-financed">
        <div>0</div>
        <p>Non_Financed</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<table class="table table-striped-table" id="invoice-data-table">

<tbody> 
<tr>
    <td>1401896</td>
    <td><input id="cbxFinancedInvoices" name="InvoiceStatus" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="cbxUnFinancedInvoices" name="InvoiceStatus" type="radio"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>EUR</td>
    <td id="invoice-amount">415</td>
    <td>7/12/2014</td>
    <td></td>        
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears from your selectors that you may have duplicate id attributes, which will cause problems. Can you please add your HTML to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any radio button is clicked in that group. Update your script to

```
var financedDiv = Number($('.financed div').html().trim());
var NonfinancedDiv = Number($('.non-financed div').html().trim());
var cbxFinancedInvioces = $('#cbxFinancedInvoices');
var cbxUnfinancedInvoices = $('#cbxUnFinancedInvoices');
var checkVal = $("input[name='InvoiceStatus']:checked").val();
cbxFinancedInvioces.on('change', function () {        
    if (this.checked) {                
        financedDiv = financedDiv + 1;
        $('.financed div').html(financedDiv);
        if(checkVal) {
            NonfinancedDiv = NonfinancedDiv - 1;
            $('.non-financed div').html(NonfinancedDiv);
        }
        checkVal = true;

    }            
});

cbxUnfinancedInvoices.on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {               
        NonfinancedDiv = NonfinancedDiv + 1;
        $('.non-financed div').html(NonfinancedDiv);
                    if(checkVal) {
            financedDiv = financedDiv - 1;
            $('.financed div').html(financedDiv);
        }
        checkVal = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work on multiple <tr> element though , can you please update that code ?
    `var cbxFinancedInvioces = $('#cbxFinancedInvoices');` onlygives the first radiobutton

Comment: I am not getting your condition, can you update it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/foauv7j7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/foauv7j7/1/   if I click 3 non-financed it should show 3, however the solution u gave works for the HTML I sent

Comment: thats because you are checking value by input name InvoiceStatus, and now there are three of them with different name. identify the groups, and check for each one. something like `var radio_groups = {}
$(":radio").each(function(){
    radio_groups[this.name] = true;
})
 
 
for(group in radio_groups){
    alert(group);
    if (true) {
    //not checked
    } else {
    //checked
    }
 
}` also you can use different class name to identify checked value  is from financed or unfinanced.